# Scope of Guardrails Driven Development - Tests and Types?

Tags: clojure, tdd

At the [Railsconf 2012](http://railsconf2012.com/) Rich Hickey gave a Keynote entitled [Simple Made Easy](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rI8tNMsozo0).

In it he made the [following satirical quote](http://www.headspring.com/guard-rail-programming/) about Test Driven Development:

“I think we’re in this world I’d like to call Guard Rail Programming… ‘I can make change because I have tests!’ Who does that? Who drives their car around, banging against the guard rails? Do the guard rails help you get to where you want to go?”

Rich's larger point was that TDD isn't valuable unless you have a strong mental model of what you want to build. You needed to know the direction you're doing in.

Given that Rich has written a dynamic (ie without types except core.typed) language called [Clojure](http://clojure.org/) - he appears to advocate a 'strong mental model' over aids like Types and Tests.

Putting all these things together. Is the usage of Types within the scope of guardrail-driven development, or is the scope of this limited to TDD?

Comment: Could you elaborate more on why you think that the usage of types would be "in the scope" of any of them? Clearly, you need to have a stronger "mental model" if you write your code in a strong typed language. In Clj, you can set type hints for the compiler as an optimization http://clojure.org/java_interop#Java%20Interop-Type%20Hints. Trying to optimize unfinished code usually is in the way of any development drive. So I'd say types are neither in the scope of "GDD" or TDD.

Comment: Yes, I'd say static typing is a guardrail. The point of a guardrail is to tell you (rather forcefully) where you can't go, which is also what static typing accomplishes. I think Rich's point is that it's a more efficient problem solving technique to focus on where you do want to get to. My intuitive understanding of this is a form of 'correctness by design'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion the point was about first clearly thinking about your problem, giving it sometime to let it settle down in your brain and let the solution evolve over a period of time rather than going the TDD way where you start writing tests as soon as you get the project and then you write code such that these tests pass - which sounds like a gaurdrail driven development.

As far as **types** are concerned, they are everywhere and I meant it literally. You can't think without types, they are the mental model of humans to understand the world around. In programming types are explicit in statically typed languages and implicit in dynamic languages . Without types you can't even program - try to write a function body without knowing the types of parameters.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughtful answer.